# Does this game that I invented correspond to a valid optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics, metaheuristics, puzzles-games

Recently, I thought of the following "game" that I would like to frame as an optimization problem:

[image]

- Assume there are five baskets. The first basket has five discrete objects (e.g., apples), the second basket has three discrete objects (e.g., oranges), the third basket has one discrete object (e.g., a watermelon), and the fourth and fifth baskets have 11 kilograms of some continuous object (e.g. coffee and rice - not the right analogy, but bear with me)
- Assume that there exists some "mysterious unobservable (discrete and non-differentiable) black box function" which assigns a cost to combinations of objects from different baskets. For example: **A1,A2, B2, D = (1 - 2.5), E = (6.1 - 7, 8.1 - 9.2)** might have a cost of "7.1" and **A1,A3, B1, C = C1 D = (1 - 8), E = (5.1 - 5.5)** might have a cost of "8.773". We have no idea how this cost is calculated, and we just have this mysterious function that assigns costs to different combinations of items from these baskets.

**For this "game", here are the rules:**

- There are three players.
- The first player chooses some items from some of these five baskets; they have the choice of ignoring baskets if they want (e.g. **A1, A2, C1, D = (1 - 3.1)** ). From the remaining items, the second player chooses some combination of items. Finally, the third player chooses items from the remainder (at the end, some items can remain unchosen by all three players).
- Once each player has made their selections, the "mysterious function" assigns a cost to each of their selections.
- This function has the general form of: **f(selection A = a, B = b, C = c, D = d, E = e) = cost**
- Let's say for the purpose of this game, the cost function isn't always "monotonic". For example f(A = A1, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0) = 3.1, f(A = A2 , B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0) = 1.6, f(A = (A1, A2) , B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0 ) = 0.89.

**The goal of the game is for:**

- **Objective:** The cost of each player's selection to be less than 10 but as close to 10 as possible
- **Constraint:** Each player should at least have one red Square in their selection
- **Thus - what is the optimal selection that each player should make such that the objective is maximized and the constraint is met?**

To me, this "game" seems to be some variant of the [knapsack optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or an assignment/resource allocation problem. In particular, this seems to be a discrete combinatorial gradient-free optimization problem.

Suppose these three players can play this game over and over while they study "how their selections influence the overall cost" and "which selections result in the cost function being closer to the desired value".

For instance:

- **Round 1:** Player_1_Cost = 12.1, Player_2_Cost = 8.5, Player_3_Cost = 19.11.  Total Cost = 30 - 39.7 = - 9 .7
- **Round 2:** Player_1_Cost = 1.5, Player_2_Cost = 0.5, Player_3_Cost = 0.  Total Cost = 30 - 2 = + 28
- **Round 1000:** Player_1_Cost = 9.5, Player_2_Cost = 7, Player_3_Cost = 8  Total Cost = 30 - 24.5 = + 5.5

In this case, the players would keep playing the game until they start to "learn" which selections will result in the "Total Cost" being closest to 0. At first, the players might simply pick random selections and observe the "Total Cost." Later, they might use a more sophisticated approach such as [evolutionary algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) and [metaheuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) to "strategically combine" successful selections from the past and gradually progress towards more optimal selections:

[image]

Can this "game" that I have created be interpreted as a (discrete combinatorial) optimization problem? Does this problem that I have created correspond to some a preexisting type of optimization problem?**

Comment: What does "A1,A2, B2, D = (1 - 2.5), E = (6.1 - 7, 8.1 - 9.2)" mean? Does it mean "take the objects A1, A2, and B2; take the range 1 - 2.5 from basket D; and take the ranges 6.1 - 7 and 8.1 - 9.2 from basket E"?

Comment: @ Tanner Swett: thank you for your reply! Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @stats_noob, would you say please, is the value of each object in the cost function deterministic or they will change in each game? I mean, for example, the cost for $A1,A2, B2, D = (1 - 2.5), E = (6.1 - 7, 8.1 - 9.2) = 7.1$ and if in the next game the assignment be the same the cost is $7.1$ or it is different?

Comment: @ A.Omidi: thank you for your reply! The value of the cost function is deterministic - it will not change with each game.

Comment: @stats_noob, thanks for your clarifying. I am not sure understand the problem as well, but based on the being the objects cost deterministic, it seems the cost function would be calculated too and this has a contradiction with the primary assumptions of the cost function. Have you thought about that or there is something else?

Comment: @A.Omidi : thank you for your reply! Which assumptions are you reffering to?

Comment: @stats_noob, `Assume that there exists some "mysterious unobservable (discrete and non-differentiable) black-box function`. I think you are facing with a deterministic function than a back-box function.

Comment: @ A. Omidi: thank you for your reply! How about I re-word everything - let's say the "cost function" in this problem is the same type of cost function as in the Travelling Salesman Problem . What would you say now?

Comment: @stats_noob, in this case, a deterministic model (MIP/CP) would be useful, and minimizing this cost with regard to the mentioned constraints is what you want.

Comment: @ A.Omidi: thank you so much for your reply! At this point, I am just interested in knowing if this "game" I invented corresponds to an Optimization Problem in general ... or is this all pure nonsense :)

Comment: @stats_noob, by the above definition, your problem might be classified as a MIP or CP as a variant of an assignment problem otherwise, it is being fallen on what Prof. Rubin mentioned.

Comment: Is *gradient-free optimization* the same as *[derivative-free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization)*?

Comment: @ Peter Mortensen: Thank you so much for your reply! Yes, I think that "gradient free optimization" is the same thing as "derivative free optimization"! :)

Answer (score 7):

Your game does not fall into classical discrete optimization as the objective is unknown. As soon as the blackbox function is fully know (or one supposes a model with fixed parameters for it) it would though. However even then due to the probably nonlinear nature of your black box i doubt there is a specific name for MINLP problem that agents solve each round.

Further thoughts:

Given that Agents 1 objective i don't see why it would cooperate with other agents to help explore the assignment space if it found an assignment that is good enough for it. And similarly Agent 2 does not care whether Agent 3 is left with a solvable problem. So i am not sure rational agents playing this game would necessarily converge towards a solution with Total Cost $= 30$.

> Objective: The cost of each player's selection to be less than 10 ...

This part of the objective is not computable, it sounds more like a constraint, if you want to express this as an objective one could say for example: the objective is $3||x-10||$ if $x<10$ and $||x-10||$ if $x \geq 10$;

Comment: @ worldsmithhelper : I can not thank you enough for your answer! Just some points I wanted to make

Comment: 1) Maybe I chose the wrong terms to describe the "function". Let's assume that we have the function that assigns costs, but this function contains several "indicator functions" and is clearly non-differentiable. Does this make the game closer to an optimization problem? (e.g. something like Travelling Salesman but where the costs are non-linear)?

Comment: 2) "Given that Agents 1 objective i don't see why it would cooperate with other agents to help explore the assignment space if it found an assignment that is good enough for it." This is a very good point - I imagine this game "hierarchical objectives". As a very loose analogy:

Comment: "if two people are on an island, when one person finds food : if he eats all the food he finds instead of sharing the food - he is in a better position compared to the start of the day (e.g. objective is to fill your stomach).  But if he shares, he is temporarily in a worse position - but there might be hidden benefits for sharing.  For example, if he shares today, it might make the other person more inclined to share when the first person is sick and cant find food - or if the other person becomes weak from not eating, he might not be able to protect the first person from an animal attack

Comment: This kind of leads to indirect cooperation between both people on the island (i.e. the agents in this game). In this game I described - the first agent might be selfish and pick items that help him meet his immediate objective ... but he will eventually realize that if he is too selfish, he will miss the overall objective and lose the game. Thus, all agents must indirectly learn to cooperate and pick items that favor their personal objectives as well as the overall objective. Does this make sense?

Comment: note for 2) : This game could be framed as a Multi Objective Optimization problem, but I decided to keep it simple for the sake of explainability

Comment: 3)  "i doubt there is a specific name for MINLP problem that agents solve each round." What i meant here is that imagine all agents in this game have the ability to keep playing this game until their selections start to converge towards the objective. I imagine that in the first round, the first agent might not be very "considerate" and act very selfishly ... but with the correct implementation of some Evolutionary Algorithm (e.g. Genetic Algorithm), it is possible that the first agent becomes more "considerate" towards the other agents, because he realizes his selfishness makes everyone lose.

Comment: The cooperation you "hope" for makes no sense in an optimization context. If you use evolutionary pressures your solver is using a different problem then you stated. Framing this as multi-objective problem makes sense, however then you loose any notion of an correct answer and due to the fact the choices of the first player constraint the choices of other players player 1 will (by the definition of pareto frontier) never result in player 1 giving up any of it's objective.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  Can you please explain why no cooperation would occur in this problem? I am ok with an evolutionary algorithm not returning the true optimal solution, as long as a "good enough" solution is found. I am curious - why do you think an evolution algorithm would result in a different problem compared to the original problem?

Comment: Suppose this is a single objective optimization problem. Let's say that the objective function only measures the total cost of all 3 players after all selections are made. Couldnt the genetic algorithm start to see which selections result in better values of the objective function - and explore similar selections?

Answer (score 4):

If we strip away the game aspects, this might be related to [simulation optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation-based_optimization). Your black box is not stochastic, but simulation optimization methods do apply to deterministic simulations as well.

Comment: @ Prubin: Thank you so much for your answer! I will check out this link - I am very curious to learn more about "simulation optimization"!